# How to get a jqGrid cell value when editing

Tags: jqgrid, cell

How to get a jqGrid cell value when in-line editing (getcell and getRowData returns the cell content and not the actuall value of the input element).

Answer (score 17):

General function to get value of cell with given row id and cell id

Create in your js code function:

```
function getCellValue(rowId, cellId) {
    var cell = jQuery('#' + rowId + '_' + cellId);        
    var val = cell.val();
    return val;
}
```

Example of use:

```
var clientId = getCellValue(15, 'clientId');
```

Dodgy, but works.

Answer (score 15):

Here is an example of basic solution with a user function.

```
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
        var cont = $('#grid').getCell(rowid, 'MyCol');
        var val = getCellValue(cont);
    }
```

...

```
function getCellValue(content) {
    var k1 = content.indexOf(' value=', 0);
    var k2 = content.indexOf(' name=', k1);
    var val = '';
    if (k1 > 0) {
        val = content.substr(k1 + 7, k2 - k1 - 6);
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: if set, the content contains always the value attribute followed by the name attribute.

Comment: This does not work. It does not pulled out the selected value, just the first one?

Comment: This part was all I needed to check for empty values: $('#grid').getCell(rowid, 'MyCol');

Answer (score 7):

After many hours grief I found this to be the simplest solution. Call this before fetching the row data:

```
$('#yourgrid').jqGrid("editCell", 0, 0, false);
```

It will save any current edit and will not throw if there are no rows in the grid.

Comment: Fantastic. This did it for me. 






To be clear, you need to call the above code before you call `$('#yourgrid').jqGrid("getCell", rowId, 'column')`.

Answer (score 4):

As you stated, [according to the jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) for getCell and getRowData:

> Do not use this method when you editing the row or cell. This will return the cell content and not the actual value of the input element

Since neither of these methods will return your data directly, you would have to use them to return the cell content itself and then parse it, perhaps using jQuery. It would be nice if a future version of jqGrid could provide a means to do some of this parsing itself, and/or provide an API to make it more straightforward. But on the other hand is this really a use case that comes up that often?

Alternatively, if you can explain your original problem in more detail there may be other options.

Comment: There is no problem at all. But I am very surprised that there is no way to get directly a jqgrid cell value without parsing content or calling a user function !...

Comment: Well, without looking at the source code I imagine the reason why is that during inline-edit the grid adds markup to display the edit controls. At this point the getCell / getRowData functions cannot be used as-is because the data in the grid may be changed out from under it. In this case the grid would have to be smart enough to do the parsing itself, that currently user code has to do. Probably the best solution would be to have the grid attempt to do this parsing itself, but provide some user API (event?) to override the grid's code if (for example) you are using controls not yet supported.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it will give you particular column's value

```
onSelectRow: function(id) {
    var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id); 
    var temp= rowData['name'];//replace name with you column
    alert(temp);
}
```

Comment: I was confused and thought rowData was a property but it is just: `jQuery('#GridTableId').getRowData(id)['name']` in case someone makes the same mistake I did

Comment: why there is UP vote for this answer, its not the answer for quetion at all.

Comment: @Meraj: because everybody comes here reading just the question title :)

Comment: This isn't right. This will not work once you are in edit mode. As the OP states you'll get HTML, not data values.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you have to save the row before you access the cell contents.

If you do, then you get the value for the cell instead of the markup that comes when the cell is in edit mode.

```
jQuery.each(selectedRows, function(index, foodId) {
            // save the row on the grid in 'client array', I.E. without a server post
            $("#favoritesTable").saveRow(foodId, false, 'clientArray'); 

            // longhand, get grid row based on the id
            var gridRow = $("#favoritesTable").getRowData(foodId);

            // reference the value from the editable cell
            foodData += foodId + ":" + gridRow['ServingsConsumed'] + ',';
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi， I met this problem too. Finally I solved this problem by jQuery. But the answer is related to the grid itself, not a common one. Hope it helps.

My solution like this:

```
var userIDContent = $("#grid").getCell(id,"userID");  // Use getCell to get the content
//alert("userID:" +userID);  // you can see the content here.

//Use jQuery to create this element and then get the required value.
var userID = $(userIDContent).val();  // var userID = $(userIDContent).attr('attrName');
```

Comment: see my answer in if `.val()` doesn't exist based on your selector mine container HTML that I was after the innerText on it so using `.text()` instead did the trick. @LLQ thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this directly....

```
onCellSelect: function(rowid,iCol,cellcontent,e) {
            alert(cellcontent);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
                function getDataLine(grida, rowid){  //vykradeno z inineeditu a vohackovano

                    if(grida.lastIndexOf("#", 0) === 0){
                        grida = $(grida);
                    }else{
                        grida = $("#"+grida);
                    }

                    var nm, tmp={}, tmp2={}, tmp3= {}, editable, fr, cv, ind;

                    ind = grida.jqGrid("getInd",rowid,true);
                    if(ind === false) {return success;}
                    editable = $(ind).attr("editable");
                    if (editable==="1") {
                        var cm;
                        var colModel = grida.jqGrid("getGridParam","colModel") ;
                        $("td",ind).each(function(i) {
                            // cm = $('#mygrid').p.colModel[i];
                            cm = colModel[i];
                            nm = cm.name;
                            if ( nm != 'cb' && nm != 'subgrid' && cm.editable===true && nm != 'rn' && !$(this).hasClass('not-editable-cell')) {
                                switch (cm.edittype) {
                                    case "checkbox":
                                        var cbv = ["Yes","No"];
                                        if(cm.editoptions ) {
                                            cbv = cm.editoptions.value.split(":");
                                        }
                                        tmp[nm]=  $("input",this).is(":checked") ? cbv[0] : cbv[1]; 
                                        break;
                                    case 'text':
                                    case 'password':
                                    case 'textarea':
                                    case "button" :
                                        tmp[nm]=$("input, textarea",this).val();
                                        break;
                                    case 'select':
                                        if(!cm.editoptions.multiple) {
                                            tmp[nm] = $("select option:selected",this).val();
                                            tmp2[nm] = $("select option:selected", this).text();
                                        } else {
                                            var sel = $("select",this), selectedText = [];
                                            tmp[nm] = $(sel).val();
                                            if(tmp[nm]) { tmp[nm]= tmp[nm].join(","); } else { tmp[nm] =""; }
                                            $("select option:selected",this).each(
                                                function(i,selected){
                                                    selectedText[i] = $(selected).text();
                                                }
                                            );
                                            tmp2[nm] = selectedText.join(",");
                                        }
                                        if(cm.formatter && cm.formatter == 'select') { tmp2={}; }
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return tmp;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution:
1. Using  this.value to get the current editing value in the editing row.
2. Save the cell value to a hidden field when the cell lost its focus.
3. Read the hidden field when you need.

The code:

```
 colModel="[
       { name: 'Net', index: 'Net', editable:true, editoptions: { dataEvents: [ { type: 'focusout', fn: function(e) {$('#HiddenNet').val(this.value);} }] }, editrules:{custom:true,}},
       { name: 'Tax', index: 'Tax', editable:true, editoptions: { dataEvents: [ { type: 'focus', fn: function(e) {this.value=$('#HiddenNet').val(); } }] }, editrules:{custom:true}}
    ]"
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from the following way...!!

```
var rowId =$("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');  
var rowData = jQuery("#list").getRowData(rowId);
var colData = rowData['UserId'];   // perticuler Column name of jqgrid that you want to access
```

Comment: the list is the jqgrid id only @sathya

Comment: can you help me for this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647113/how-to-get-jqgrid-first-row-data-with-out-select-in-jsp

Answer (score 1):

In my case the contents of my cell is HTML as result of a formatter. I want the value inside anchor tag. By fetching the cell contents and then creating an element out of the html via jQuery I am able to then access the raw value by calling .text() on my newly created element.

```
var cellContents = grid.getCell(rowid, 'ColNameHere');
console.log($(cellContents)); 
//in my case logs <h3><a href="#">The Value I'm After</a></h3>

var cellRawValue = $(cellContents).text();
console.log(cellRawValue); //outputs "The Value I'm After!"
```

my answer is based on @LLQ answer, but since in my case my cellContents isn't an input I needed to use `.text()` instead of `.val()` to access the raw value so I thought I'd post this in case anyone else is looking for a way to access the raw value of a formatted jqGrid cell.

Answer (score 1):

its very simple write code in you grid.php and pass the value to an other page.php
in this way you can get other column cell vaue

but any one can make a like window.open(path to pass value....) in fancy box or clor box?

```
$custom = <<<CUSTOM
jQuery("#getselected").click(function(){

    var selr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow'); 
    var kelr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getCell', selr, 'stu_regno');
    var belr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getCell', selr, 'stu_school');
    if(selr) 

     window.open('editcustomer.php?id='+(selr), '_Self');


    else alert("No selected row");
    return false;
});

CUSTOM;
$grid->setJSCode($custom);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an extension of this would get it for you.
[retrieving-original-row-data-from-jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788360/retrieving-original-row-data-from-jqgrid)

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution than using getCell which as you know returns some html when in edit mode is to use jquery to access the fields directly.  The problem with trying to parse like you are doing is that it will only work for input fields (not things like select), and it won't work if you have done some customizations to the input fields.  The following will work with inputs and select elements and is only one line of code.

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
    var val = $('#' + rowid + '_MyCol').val();
}
```

Comment: This does not work, and your JQuery selector is wrong, should be something like  $('#'+rowid+' [aria-describedby$=_'+'colName'+']'). But this gets the cell, you still cant retrieve the value withouth parsing.

Comment: Works great for me.  By "cell" do you mean the <td>?  What I am seeing is this will get the value of the edit control, whatever that is, and also assuming that you haven't done any customizations to the input control as stated in the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a rather indirect way. Your data should have an unique id.

First, setting a formatter

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.fmatter, {          
numdata: function(cellvalue, options, rowdata){
    return '<span class="numData" data-num="'+rowdata.num+'">'+rowdata.num+'</span>';
}
});
```

Use this formatter in ColModel. To retrieve ID (e.g. selected row)

```
var grid = $("#grid"), 
    rowId = grid.getGridPara('selrow'),
    num = grid.find("#"+rowId+" span.numData").attr("data-num");
```

(or you can directly use .data() for latest jquery 1.4.4)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the cell value when in-line editing you need to capture this event(or another similar event, check [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing)):

beforeSaveCell: function (rowid, celname, value, iRow, iCol) { }

In the value parameter you have the 'value' of the cell that was currently edited.

To get the the rest of the values in the row use getRowData()

I lost a lot of time with this, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to attach an object containing orignal values to each tr element in the grid. I've used afterAddRecord callback to get my hands on the values before jqGrid throws them away and jQuery's "data" method to store them in the work.

Example:

```
afterInsertRow: function( rowid, rowdata, rowelem ) {
  var tr = $("#"+rowid);
  $(tr).data("jqgrid.record_data", rowelem);
},
```

“rowelem” is the array of cell values from our JSON data feed or [jsonReader] (http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function)

Then at any point I can fetch those attributes using:

```
$(tr).data(“jqgrid.record_data”).
```

More at: http://wojciech.oxos.pl/post/9423083837/fetching-original-record-values-in-jqgrid

Answer (score 0):

I think that Aidan's answer is by far the best.

```
$('#yourgrid').jqGrid("editCell", 0, 0, false);
```

This commits any current edits, giving you access to the real value.  I prefer it because:

> - You don't have to hard-code any cell references  in.
>
>   - It is particularly well suited to using getRowData() to get the entire grid, as it doesn't care which cell you've just been editing.
>   - You're not trying to parse some markup generated by jqGrid which may change in future.
>   - If the user is saving, then ending the edit session is likely the behaviour they would want anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Before i was getting : 
html tag of the textbox something like

but Here is the solution to get the value from that particular column, working and tested

```
function getValue(rowId, cellId) {
        var val = $("[rowId='"+rowId+"'][name='"+cellId+"']").val();
        return val;
       }

var values = getValue(rowId, 'cellid');
```

Answer (score 0):

I obtain edit value using javascript:

document.getElementById('idCell').value

I hope this info useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the original value before the formatter, so this is what I did:

```
{
    name: 'Slot', title: false, formatter: function (cellValue, options, rowObject) {
        rowObject['SlotID'] = cellValue;  // <--- This saves the original ID
        if (somelogic) {
            return someString;
        } else {
            return someOtherString;
        }
    }
},
{ name: 'SlotID', hidden: true }
```

Now `SlotID` contains the original ID.  Also, you don't need to have SlotID property on your original model.

Answer (score -1):

try subscribing to afterEditCell event it will receive (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) where value is your a new value of your cell

Answer (score -2):

You can use getCol to get the column values as an array then index into it by the row you are interested in.

```
var col = $('#grid').jqGrid('getCol', 'Sales', false);

var val = col[row];
```

Comment: This don't work. getCol returns the same result as getCell and getRowData:  the cell content and not the actuall value of the input element...