# Get the client side value of a grid cell containing a <select>

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to write a jquery function that scans the whole of a jqrid to check if any of its cells have a value.

The issue I am having is that there does not seem to be a way of retrieving the selected value of a cell that contains a select box. The jqgrid [docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) clearly states the following for the `getCell` and `getRowData` methods.

> Do not use this method when you
>   editing the row or cell. This will
>   return the cell content and not the
>   actuall value of the input element

**Which is fair enough, but given that, how do I actually get the value?**

Its not possible to parse the html that is returned from the select content, as none of the options are flagged as selected, even if they appear to be selected in the browser.

For reference here is a snippet of my code:

```
var colModels = this.grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
for (i = 1; i < colModels.length; i++) {
            var colModel = colModels[i];
            if (colModel.edittype == 'select') {
                var colData = this.grid.jqGrid('getCol', colModel.name, false);
                for (j = 0; j < colData.length; j++) {
                    if (colData[j] != 0) {
                        //alert("select change: " + colData[j]);
                        //alert(j+' GridName_' + colModel.name)
                        //alert("select change: " + $('#GridName_' + colModel.name).val());
                        //return has value?;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
```

Column definiton:

```
{ name: "AppleId", index: "Appled", width: 150, align: "left", resizable: false, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: function() { return xxx.buildAppleSelect(); } }, formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject, action) { return xxx.buildAppleSelectHtml(cellvalue); } };
```

I also experimented with [afterEditCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing) and other similar events - but the problem with these is that - clicking the select box does not put the sell in edit mode - you have to click the cell first and then the select.

In short - how do I get the selected value, client side - can it be done?

There are simular questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581384/how-to-get-selects-value-in-jqgrid-when-using-select-editoptions-on-a-column), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775524/how-to-get-a-jqgrid-cell-value) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573710/how-to-get-a-cell-value-in-jqgrid). But none seem to tackle the issue (client side).

Answer (score 0):

No. Here is some HTML that I obtained from a test grid using `getRowData`:

```
<select class="editable" size="1" name="test" id="5_test">
 <option value="0">Zero</option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
 <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

You are right - there is not enough information in the markup to determine which value is selected. In order to get the selected value you will have to bring the row out of edit mode, for example by using grid method `saveRow`.

Comment: No this wont work - to be clear, html like this is always return (i.e. no selected option). regardless of whether the cell in edit mode or not.

Comment: OK... I have grids in production code that use selects. In these grids I used `editable: true,edittype:"select"}` to indicate they use dropdowns. Then when I want to get the selected value I just use `getRowData` and say `data.ColumnName`, which contains the value of the selected item in the dropdown. Am I missing something? Are you trying to get the row to always display a dropdown, even when it is not being edited??

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of the jQuery you are using that gets the actual value out then please. When I try this: `$('#MyGrid').getRowData(-1).APropertyWithSelect`. Although your last comment has got me thinking. As yes, I am always showing the dropdown, even when its not being edited. That  must be the problem?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the problem. jqGrid expects to hide the dropdown for rows that are not being edited.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me Dan that you thy to go in a wrong way. I am not really understand why you do want to have grid cell containing of `<select>`, but if you'll explain me what do you want I am sure I'll find a solution of you problem.

First I explain what I find strange in your question. If you define `edittype: "select"`, then jqGid has typically a string and not a `<select>` element inside. If you are in en edit mode (for example in inline edit mode), then all other rows excepting selected row has also a string and not a `<select>` element inside. If user make a chose and press enter, the edit mode will be ended and the modified data will be saved (or send to the server). So it is also not important which values were displayed before.

It seems to me you have some problems because of some custom building of values in `buildAppleSelect` and custom formatting in `buildAppleSelectHtml`.

If you be want see intermediate values from select you can use `dataEvents` with `'change'` in the `editoptions`.

I hope now you understand what I find strange in your question. If you explain me what is your problem and why you do have more then one `<select>` element and want to read intermediate select values I'll try to find a solution for you.

**UPDATED**: I posted a code which shows how use `dataEvents` with `'change'` in [JQGrid Inline Editing : Filter subcategory dropdown list based on another category dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213330/jqgrid-inline-editing-filter-subcategory-dropdown-list-based-on-another-categor/3221372#3221372). Probably it will help you.

Comment: Oleg - I need a cell to contain a dropdown box, that is why a `select` is needed. I dont entirely understand your first query - but I cant rely on any variable being sent to the server, for this function, I need the client side value. Im not sure the `buildAppleSelect` and `buildAppleSelectHtml` methods are a fault, as these are only called when the grid is first built. Ill have alook at dataEvents to see if that give me what I need.

Comment: What I want to say is that the column with `edittype: "select"` has a string as a value and not a html fragment with `<select>`. The only row which has a `<select>` is a row which is in edit mode. So you can have problem only with one cell in the grid. I don't understand why you need have a current selection of `<select>` before the row should not be saved. If you have more then one `<select>` in the same row and try to modify one `<select>` based on the currect selection on another `<select>` you can use `dataEvents` with `'change'`.