# jqGrid not data display in the grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

In an ASP.NET MVC 3.0 application, I use jqGrid. I use the code below. I see the grid but no data in. I passed in the "GridData" action, the list content is one element but nothing in the grid.

C# :

```
public ActionResult GridData()
{

    List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
    list.Add(new Customer() { Code = "AAA", FirstName = "BBB", LastName = "CCC" });

    return Json(list);
}
```

HTML :

```
<table id="jqgProducts" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="jqgpProducts" style="text-align:center;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#jqgProducts').jqGrid({
            //url from wich data should be requested
            url: '/Customer/GridData/',
            //type of data
            datatype: 'json',
            //url access method type
            mtype: 'GET',
            //columns names
            colNames: ['Id', 'LastName','FirstName', 'Code'],
            //columns model
            colModel: [
                  { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', align: 'left' },
                  { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', align: 'left' },
                  { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', align: 'left' },
                  { name: 'Code', index: 'Code', align: 'left' }
                ],
            //pager for grid
            pager: $('#jqgpProducts'),
            //number of rows per page
            rowNum: 10,
            //initial sorting column
            sortname: 'Id',
            //initial sorting direction
            sortorder: 'asc',
            //we want to display total records count
            viewrecords: true
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should return JSON data from the MVC action using `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` as the second parameter of jqGrid.

You next and the main problem is the data format. There are default data format which wait jqGrid. The format is described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data). So you can either produce the JSON data in the standard format like suggested you Saad or add `jsonReader` parameter to the jqGrid which will describe how your current JSON data can be read. So with almost the same `GridData`:

```
public ActionResult GridData() {
    var list = new List<Customer> {
        new Customer {Id = "myid1", Code = "AAA", FirstName = "BBB", LastName = "CCC"}
    };

    return Json (list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

you can add the following `jsonReader` parameter

```
jsonReader: {
    id: "Id",
    repeatitems: false,
    root: function (obj) { return obj; },
    page: function () { return 1; },
    total: function () { return 1; },
    records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
}
```

to read the data. Ho you can see in the code above I added `Id` property to the `Customer` class. The property can be a string of integer. Both will be OK for jqGrid. The `Id` value will be saved twice: one time as the `id` of the `<tr>` element of the row of the grid and once as the `<td>` element of the first table column. If you never need to display the id for the user you can remove the `Id` column from the grid, but still place `id` in the JSON data. It you will use non-unique ids you could have the same problems like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022746/jqgrid-selection-issue-with-duplicates-columns).

Another way will be to change the code of the MVC Action so that it produces the JSON data in the default format. To do this you can change the code of the `GridData` to the following:

```
public ActionResult GridData() {
    var list = new List<Customer> {
        new Customer {Id = "myid1", Code = "AAA", FirstName = "BBB", LastName = "CCC"}
    };
    return Json (new {
        page = 1,
        total = 1,
        records = list.Count,
        rows = (from x in list
                orderby x.Id
                select new {
                    id = x.Id,
                    cell = new[] {
                        x.Code,
                        x.FirstName,
                        x.LastName
                    }
                }
        )
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

All the code above I included only for understanding of the jqGrid basics. In the code above the data will be sorted by `Id` which corresponds to the `sortname: 'Id'` which you use in the jqGrid. The name will be send to the server as the `sidx` parameter. Additionally the parameters `sortorder: 'asc'` and `rowNum: 10` of the jqGrid will define the values of `sord` and `rows` parameters of the action. The last parameter `page` send to the server will be initially set to 1 and will be increased if the user choose the next page. So typical prototype of the MVC action is

```
public ActionResult GridData (string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
```

I recommend you to read [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835957/jquery-with-asp-net-mvc-calling-ajax-enabled-web-service/2836817#2836817) and the UPDATED part of the next [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644). I hope the answers bring you forward in the usage of jqGrid. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764709/jqgrid-not-loading-data/5766189#5766189) you will find the answer on the question: why the default format of the JSON data, which jqGrid wait for, looks so strange.

Answer (score 1):

We're also using jqGrid in our [project](http://xenta.net). Check these two links: [controller](http://xenta.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/11190#161884)(LoadApplicationGrid) and [view](http://xenta.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/11190#161918). And [here](http://xenta.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/11190#118423) our JQGridView custom Json result.

Also, you can allow GET method for the Json result using [JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonrequestbehavior.aspx), then call the action directly from the browser and compare the serialized data with jqGrid requirements.

Comment: Well I follow your code did the same here .... grid still empty. I thnik I'm going back to datadable or other solution

Comment: Ok. Maybe there an error with jqGrid initialization. Check this link http://xenta.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/11201#117958. There a lot of code in file, take a look at js code starting with " @if(Html.IsScriptRegistered("jqGrid"))". Also, it seems like you send the response as serialized list w/o page index, page count and total count(you pass the List to the Json method, we pass anon object). Take a look at our jsonReader settings.

Comment: `var jsonData = new
            {
                pageIndex = pageIndex + 1,
                pageCount = pageCount,
                totalCount = totalCount,
                data = data.ToArray()
            };

            return Json(jsonData);` - This way we create an anon object for serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I think your controller throws an exception in `GridData()`, because MVC3 doesn't allow JSON answers to GET requests by default.
You may modify this behavior like this:

```
public ActionResult GridData()
{  
    List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
    list.Add(new Customer() { Code = "AAA", FirstName = "BBB", LastName = "CCC" });

    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: You should probably use a debugger then, and get some more information on your problem

Comment: You think I don't use a debugger? :) With a debugger point in the return the list has 1 element. I just can't tell you more.

Comment: The answer, when I call the page is : [{"FirstName":"BBB","LastName":"CCC","Id":39,"Code":"AAA"}]

Comment: So the problem is in your client code, not in your server code. That's already a lot of additional information

Answer (score 0):

try this code segment. i always create a JqgridRow to return in Json.

```
public ActionResult GridData()
```

{

```
List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
list.Add(new Customer() { Code = "AAA", FirstName = "BBB", LastName = "CCC" });

var GetData = new
                {
                    rows = (from x in list 
                            select new JqGridRow()
                            {
                                cell = new string[] {
                                    x.Code.ToString(),
                                    x.FirstName.ToString(),
                                    x.LastName .ToString(),
                                }
                            }
                            ).ToArray()
                };

return Json(GetData , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

}

hope this help..

Comment: from the dll  'Lib.Web.Mvc' you can get it from http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/63274

Comment: namespace? I searched for this method but didn't and the author doesn't talk about this method in the chm file (help). No other way than use extra lib ?

Comment: i use this way to fill the grid, it seems to be easier.

Comment: I can't test it because "JqGridRow" is unknown even when the DLL to the reference

Comment: i have a project which contain the complete code of this library. tell me your maling id i ll email you if u want.