# get the cells value of the selected row of JQGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid-asp.net

How can I get the selected cell value in JQgrid?

I have looked through examples where you get the selected row id and then get the cell value based on passing the column name to 'getcell' 
from [How to get a jqGrid selected row cells value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995129/how-to-get-a-jqgrid-selected-row-cells-value)
e.g.

```
var grid = jQuery('#list');
var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'MyColName');
```

Is there any way to get the cell value based on the selected cell without having to specify the column name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

outisde of jqgrid make a variable like

```
var selectedVal;
```

then inside the jqgrid initialisation use the onCellSelect to populate that variable with the cells content. check here for the event http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events

Alternatively you could use that same event to store the cells informations like row_id and column index in a variable, then use the "getCell" method with the information from the row and cell variables

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using onSelectRow, it is much easier to use the onCellSelect of the JQGrid
for it automatically gives you the value of your selected cell.

**Example Code:**

```
onCellSelect : function(rowid, col, content, e) {
      alert(content);
    );
}
```

**Extra Details:**

- ***rowid*** is the id of the row
- ***col*** is the index of the cell,
- ***content*** is the content of the cell,
- ***e*** is the event object element where we click.

(Note that this available when we not use cell editing module and is disabled when using cell editing).