# how to get row id of selected row in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am writing this code and calling the method on rowdoubleclick of the jqgrid. I have also given all the tags and the column names of my jqgrid. Can you help me figure out why I am getting "undefined" when I alert the values?

```
<cc1:JQGrid ID="grdUserDetails" runat="server" Width="770px" Height="350px" ClientSideEvents-RowDoubleClick="ForwardDetails">
                <Columns>
                    <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="VisitorID" HeaderText="ID" TextAlign="Left" PrimaryKey="true"
                        Visible="false" Searchable="false">
                    </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                    <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="PersonName" HeaderText="Visitor" TextAlign="Left">
                    </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                    <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="Company Name" TextAlign="Left">
                    </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                    <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="ContactNumber" HeaderText="Contact Number" TextAlign="Left">
                    </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                    <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" TextAlign="Left">
                    </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                    <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" TextAlign="Left">
                    </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                    <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="DisplayDate" HeaderText="Last Visited on" TextAlign="Left">
                    </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                </Columns>
                <PagerSettings PageSize="15" PageSizeOptions="[15,25,50]" />
                <ToolBarSettings ShowSearchButton="false" ShowRefreshButton="true" ShowSearchToolBar="true">
                </ToolBarSettings>
                <AppearanceSettings ShowRowNumbers="true" ></AppearanceSettings>
                <SearchToolBarSettings SearchToolBarAction="SearchOnKeyPress" />
            </cc1:JQGrid>

 function ForwardDetails() {
        var PersonName, Address, CompanyName, ContactNumber, Email;
        var selectedRowId, cellValue;
        var myGrid = $('#grdUserDetails');
         selectedRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
         cellValue = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selectedRowId, 'Visitor Name');
        window.opener.setValues(PersonName, Address, CompanyName, ContactNumber, Email);
        window.close();           
    }
```

Answer (score 23):

try this:

```
var myGrid = $('#list'),
selectedRowId = myGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
cellValue = myGrid.jqGrid ('getCell', selectedRowId, 'columnName');
```

where `columnName` is the column you provided in the `name` property of `colModel`

and `#list` is the id of your grid.

[ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995129/how-to-get-a-jqgrid-selected-row-cells-value) , [ref2](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/selection/selectedrow_client/default.php)

Comment: i am calling this method but when i debug it selectedRowId  is undefined why is that? i copy pasted your code and changed the name of  the grid id and the column name

Comment: can you post some code or a jsfiddle in your question?  it will be much helpful