# Are there different products of jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, html5builder

I have Html 5 builder XE5 and installed the jqGrid from [YouTUbe how to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-dbpHUdhfY)
Moreover I found an answer to my problem at [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995129/how-to-get-a-jqgrid-selected-row-cells-value?rq=1) but when I add this to my H5B I get no reaction at the document.write line on a new page. WHat do I wrong? I my jqGrid not the same for what that answer is? My code looks like this:

```
   function jqgrid1JSDblClickRow($sender, $params)

   {

    ?>
    //begin js

        var grid = $("#jqGrid");
        var rowKey = grid.getGridParam("selrow");

        if (rowKey)
            alert("Selected row primary key is: " + rowKey);
        else
            alert("No rows are selected");

    //end
    <?php
    }
```

the fabove function is a JS event function at OnDblClickRow at my jqgrid.
I am a little bit confused. COuld any help me please?
Thanks

Edit: Now always comes "No rows are selected", even when I select a row.

Comment: You shouldn't use `document.write()` after the page has been fully rendered. It will overwrite the page. You should use DOM modification functions.

Comment: @Bamar thanks, but its only for testing. I would like to get the colDATA for a new SQL Select. It should display more details to the selected data item in the grid. How can I do this - I am totally newbee. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you need to do another SQL select, you need to do an AJAX call to the server. If you want to display this in a subgrid, jQgrid has built-in methods for that, see the jQgrid web site for details.

Comment: This is the event **handler** for a possible double click event. Have you attached this handler to an event? Please show where you have defined the jqGrid event **listener**

Comment: @jasonscript I do that in HTML 5 Builder, and the handler is filled in to the OnDblClickRow proterty. when I delete the 3 var lines and write document.write('Hi'); then the Hi is written properly. I though I could use the  Answer to get the selected "PZeile" data.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, but is my jqGrid I downloaded from the mentioned site compatible to your jQgrid? Are there different products? Or all jqGrid the same?

Comment: I think it's unlikely that there are two different widgets both called jQgrid. They might just be different versions.

Comment: That site is talking about `DBgrid`, not `jQgrid`.

Comment: @Barmar yes I think so too. Could you explain me what var grid = $("#jqGrid"); mean? Can I access so the jqGrid component in HTML 5 BUilder ?

Comment: `$("#jqGid")` is a jQuery call that returns the element with `id="jqGrid"`. It then assigns this to the `grid` variable. I don't know anything about HTML5 Builder, I've never heard of it before now.