# Getting id as undefined when jqgrid row is clicked

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to get the `id` of the selected row, to highlight it. But I get `id` as undefined. What could be the reason for it?

I have attached a `click` event with `UserDetails` jqgrid. The following function is invoked when the `UserDetails` grid is clicked.

```
var selectUserGrid = function(event) {
   var grid = $('#UserDetails');
      grid.jqGrid( {
         onSelectRow : function(id) {
            var i = id;
         }
      });
   grid.setSelection(i,true);
}
```

How do I get the `ID` of the row clicked?

Comment: I believe you had the same question earlier?

Comment: @Pekka This one is different.

Comment: why don't you put `grid.setSelection(i,true);` code inside `onSelectRow :` handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you have the problem with the order of processing of `click` event.

The first problem is in registering of additional `click` event handler. Why you do this? jqGrid already registered one `click` event handler. jqGrid process it and it calls `beforeSelectRow` callback, trigger `jqGridBeforeSelectRow` event then it selects the row, it calls `onSelectRow` callback, trigger `jqGridSelectRow` event, calls `onCellSelect` callback, trigger trigger `jqGridCellSelect`. In other words jqGrid process `click` event and allows to use callbacks and events to do some additional actions, which *synchronized* with internal work of jqGrid.

If you register **the second** `click` handler then you could not quarantine that *your* `click` handler will be called **after** the row of the grid is selected.

I recommend you to use callback or events described above. Moreover you use `setSelection` in the code fragment which you posted. On the other side it's not clear *how you fill the grid*. You can call `setSelection` only after the corresponding row will be inserted in jqGrd. I suppose that your real code is another. Nevertheless the code which you posted can't work. Moreover the code defines `i` variable **inside of** `onSelectRow` callback, but you try to use it in **outside** of the callback. In the case `i` will be `undefined` forever.