# JqGrid get column value

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a function in which i have collection of selected rows like

```
var saveSelectedRows = $(this).getGridParam('selarrrow');
```

how to get specific column value of these selected rows.please help.

Comment: i think this is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995129/how-to-get-a-jqgrid-selected-row-cells-value

Answer (score 0):

The result of your operation is array which contain the id of the selected rows.
You can loop over this array and use getRowData to get the value of certain column

```
for ( var i = 0; i < saveSelectedRows.length; i++)
{
    var rowdata  = $("#grid").jqGrid("getRowData", saveSelectedRows[i[);
    if(rowdata.column_name == column_value) {
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

where column_name is a name from colModel