# jqGrid setCell calculated value

Tags: php, javascript, jqgrid

I need to develop a grid using jqGrid and PHP what has 4 columns: **Product**, **Quantity**, **Price** and **Amount**. The product name is retrieved from the database. If the user edits the Quantity and Price columns, the **amount** cell should be changed automatically by multiplying the **Quantity** and **Price** columns. I've tried as follows:

```
var grid = $("#reportTable");

........

afterSaveCell: function (rowid, name, val, iRow, iCol) {
  grid.jqGrid("setCell", rowid, "amount", val, "");
  calculateTotal();
}
```

Please note that the *calculateTotal()* can calculate well the grand summary of the **Quantity** column without any error, and can show on the footer of the grid perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you use [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing). In the case the [afterSaveCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) callback is really good place to update the calculated column `amount` based on the current values from the columns `quantity` and `price`. The corresponding code could be about the following

```
afterSaveCell: function (rowid, cellname, value) {
    var quantity, price, $this;
    if (cellname === 'quantity' || cellname === 'price') {
        $this = $(this);
        quantity = parseFloat($this.jqGrid("getCell", rowid, 'quantity'));
        price = parseFloat($this.jqGrid("getCell", rowid, 'price'));
        $this.jqGrid("setCell", rowid, 'amount', quantity * price);
    }
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UpdateAfterCellSave.htm) do almost the same, but calculate 'total' as the sum of 'amount' and 'tax'. For the test you should modify the value from 'amount' or 'tax' column and verify that 'total' will be recalculated.