# jQgrid delete value depending on content

Tags: jqgrid

I just want to delete the value of an cell depending on its content. If the content is 0 i want to delete it when one tries to edit it. So i choose the beforeEditCell event and tried to delete the content in that way.

```
beforeEditCell:function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol){
                            if(value == 0) value = '';
                       },
```

I tested it with alert so the event fires the alert, but I have no idea how to delete the old content.

Answer (score 0):

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655426/jqgrid-setcell-calculated-value)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247138/jqgrid-change-cell-value-and-stay-in-edit-mode)

Example from
http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/set-cell-value-to-empty/

(they're changing value to empty)

```
setCell("10″, "tax", '', {color:'red','text-align':'center'}',{title:'Sales Tax'}))
```