# Jquery JQGrid - How to get the contents of a cell in edit mode?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid with 2 editable cells, and can get the value of the current cell with:

```
var editedValue = this.value;
```

But how do I get the value of the other cell?  Currently I'm using the very ugly:

```
var otherValue = this.parentNode.nextSibling.firstChild.value;
```

But this is not safe (and has cross browser issues).

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods says that the `getCell` method can not be used when editing a row - so how can you get the value of a cell when it is in edit mode?

Comment: dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775524/how-to-get-a-jqgrid-cell-value

Comment: That one is confusing and has no accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer it myself with this simple jquery function:

```
function GetEditCellValue(rowSelector, cellName) {
    var rowId = rowSelector.split('_')[0];
    return  $("#" + rowId + "_" + cellName).val();
}
```

Call it from the column's dataEvent like so:

```
dataEvents:
    [
    { type: 'blur',  fn: function (e) {
        var someEditedValue = GetEditCellValue(this.id, "SomeColumnName");
```