# getting html value with getCell jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

long story short, when I'm trying to get value of any column with this

```
var Id=jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getCell',id,'Id');
```

I'm getting this value

```
<INPUT style="WIDTH: 98%" id=2_Id class=editable role=textbox value=86 name=Id>
```

and i"m expecting 86 only. any guess what is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a jqGrid cell value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775524/how-to-get-a-jqgrid-cell-value) `:)`

Comment: yea, i have looked there, but with this method i'm supposed to get 86 not html..any idea why is it coming?

Comment: Hiya, I think you need to grab the `value` attribute try - `.val()` or `.prop('value')`

Comment: if i try to go with .val() i get a javascript error that object not supported

Answer (score 0):

Its getting the content inside as text, which in this case is the control. You can use

```
var Id=jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getCell',id,'Id').attr("value");
```

if that suffices.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775524/how-to-get-a-jqgrid-cell-value, 2nd answer of this question works

Answer (score 0):

var rowData =  $("#jqGridTableId").getRowData(rowId);

rowData will be like:
Object {seriesId: "", name: `"<input type='text' value='Initial Jobless Claims' id='txtChartSeriesName_0'">`}

To get value of this html element from rowData....you can have a simple code like:
**$(rowData.name).val()**

Comment: almost after 3 years i needed this, but thanks anyways

Comment: May be a person like me can get help, who struggled for 2-3 hours. :)