# Get the cell value in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

How to get the particular **jqgrid** cell value using java script?For example the jqgrid having four columns like id,name,subject1,subject2.now I click the particular row and I need to get the id.how to achieve this?I use the onSelectRow in jqgrid I get the solution but I need to get the javascript?

I use the Jqgrid onSelectRow

```
  onSelectRow: function(id){
                  var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id); 
                  var temp= rowData['name'];
                  alert(temp);
                  }
```

Comment: [here's an example where they get selected row](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/selection/selectedrow_client/default.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775524/how-to-get-a-jqgrid-cell-value

Answer (score 0):

As [@ClydeFlog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1173390/clydefrog) showed in the example, try this:

```
var Id = jQuery('#gridName').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
```

See the result below in the console:

[image]

[Page example on the 'Get Selected Rows' button click](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/selection/selectedrow_client/default.php).

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Done @ρяσѕρєяK!